# SQL Bulk insert: update rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a process that bulk inserts into a table from a CSV. I now have requirements that some data coming from the CSV will contain 'updated' records (data that was imported previously but now have changes).

At this point I have a table full of duplicates. Is it possible to have BULK INSERT update (or even delete before insert) the records based on the PK?

I would rather not add a second step to this process to remove duplicates.

Edit: Instead of a staging table I'm just going to run the a delete query similar to the following

```
declare @tbl table
(
id int,
ref nvarchar(10)
)

insert into @tbl
values(1, 'AAAA'),
(2, 'BBBB'),
(3, 'CCCC'),
(4, 'AAAA'),
(5, 'BBBB'),
(6, 'AAAA')

delete from @tbl where id in (
select id from
(
select
    id,
    ref,
    RANK() OVER(partition by ref order by id desc) as rnk
from @tbl) d
where rnk > 1
)

select * from @tbl
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it were me, I would load to a staging table and do the dupout from there.  I'm not sure if BCP has that functionality, but I would be concerned about any sort of logic being done that I don't have direct and visible control over.

It would also prevent you from being able to do QC checks based on the data you are loading.  With a staging table you can do a PK comparison of some sort to make sure you have the correct number of distinct values.

Comment: I was hoping to not have a staging table, but I guess thats how it has to be.

Comment: @dustin - You really have a lot more control with a staging table, and if there is selective logic in the process you want to be able to script it out yourself.

Comment: @DustinDavis, It is really hard to tell what data is crap/junk when it is still in a file. A staging table is your last change to keep that crap/junk data out of your actual tables. It is really hard to find and remove crap/junk data after you load it into your actual tables, so it is best to just keep that crap/junk out in the first place.

Comment: I'm just going to run a query (shown in my question) after the bulk insert to remove duplicates. There is no junk data and the data isn't critical so no need for the added compl;exity of staging table. Just need to delete the old record.

Answer (score 3):

Go with a staging table and do an upsert (MERGE - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522.aspx)

Even if you were to look at SSIS for this operation and insert missing rows in one stream, I would still bulk insert the updates to a staging table on the other stream and run a single UPDATE in a SQL Task, because running a SQL Command on the individual rows for update is NOT very fast.

Answer (score 2):

Bulk load into a staging table with an identity, that way you can know the order they were load in, and can handle any duplicates.  You can then populate your actual tables in many different ways (use the first/last occurrence of a dup row, etc), including [MERGE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx).